# Pattern Recognition Puzzle

Tags: pattern, visual

I've made a pattern recognition puzzle.

**The Goal:** Find the next shape(Left to right).

**Note:** Don't take the thickness of the shapes OR the size of the shapes into consideration when solving this puzzle.
[image: puzzle]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe it is

> D

Since

> Firstly, the image rotates 90 degrees clockwise and, secondly, the shapes rotate in a cycle. Thirdly, the number of black small squares increase every step.

Comment: That's correct.
Good job!

Answer (score 0):

"D" right ?? The solution  is in picture given below
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is

> D. In each picture the internal shape is the one that is by itself in the previous picture.